# Wrong coordinate points bing maps

Tags: c#, xaml, windows-phone-8.1, bing-maps

I trying to cut the map to many rectangle parts and show ellipse in center like this:

[image: demo]

But the result is this:

[image: Screenshot 1]
[image: Screenshot 2]

XAML:

```
<Maps:MapControl x:Name="BingMap" Loaded="BingMap_Loaded">
    <Maps:MapItemsControl x:Name="MapPins">
        <Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Ellipse Fill="Red" Width="20" Height="20"></Ellipse>
                    <TextBlock Maps:MapControl.Location="{Binding Point}" Text="{Binding Count}" FontSize="20" Margin="5"/>
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </Maps:MapItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </Maps:MapItemsControl>
</Maps:MapControl>
```

C#:

```
public async Task<List<Location>> ClusterCenters(double x)
{
    List<Location> locations = new List<Location>();

    for (double i = -85; i <= 85; i+=x)
    {
        for (double j = -170; j <= 170; j+=x*2)
        {
            locations.Add(new Location()
            {
                Count = 1,
                Title = String.Format("{0},{1}", i, j),
                Point = new Geopoint(new BasicGeoposition() {
                    Latitude = i,
                    Longitude = j
                })
            });
        }
    }

    return locations;
}

private async void BingMap_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    MapPins.ItemsSource = await ClusterCenters(10);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to remember that earth isn't flat :) Maps use always some [projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Map_projection) to draw earth to 2D map. Because of this your points don't seem to be in right places.

Bing maps uses [Mercator projection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mercator_projection). You can find more information about Bings mapping system from [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb259689.aspx). There is sample code to calculate from screen coordinates to latitude and longitude(PixelXYToLatLong function).